# How can I perform an "alias" with nginx?

Tags: nginx

I am using the default nginx config for localhost, which translates  requests to `http://localhost` to files in `/home/velour/www`. 
That's all working normal.

Now I am trying to translate requests to `http://localhost/movies` to the directory `/home/velour/Videos/` (I want to be able to watch movies over my local network from other devices). So far I have tried this (I have had success using `alias` in a similar way with apache)

```
location /movies/ {
    alias /home/velour/Videos/;
}
```

nginx conf:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    #listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /home/velour/www;

    index  index.php index.html index.htm;

    autoindex on;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    #server_name _;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /movies/ {
        alias /home/velour/Videos/;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;

}
```

- *What is currently happening?* - nginx is returning 301 and redirecting browser back to `/`.

  Relevant output from `/var/log/nginx/error.log` (verbose `debug` mode):

  ```
  2016/02/06 17:33:27 [debug] 27630#0: *222 http request line: "GET /movies HTTP/1.1"
  2016/02/06 17:33:27 [debug] 27630#0: *222 http uri: "/movies"
  2016/02/06 17:33:27 [debug] 27630#0: *222 test location: "/"
  2016/02/06 17:33:27 [debug] 27630#0: *222 test location: "movies"
  2016/02/06 17:33:27 [debug] 27630#0: *222 using configuration "/movies"
  2016/02/06 17:33:27 [debug] 27630#0: *222 trying to use dir: "" "/home/velour/Videos"
  2016/02/06 17:33:27 [debug] 27630#0: *222 try file uri: ""
  2016/02/06 17:33:27 [debug] 27630#0: *222 http filename: "/home/velour/Videos"
  2016/02/06 17:33:27 [debug] 27630#0: *222 HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
  Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
  Date: Sat, 06 Feb 2016 04:33:27 GMT
  ```
- *What do I want to happen?* - nginx to give an index listing of the  `/home/velour/Videos/` directory whenever a request to `http://localhost/movies` is made.

Comment: I have a similar config, the only difference I can see is that I don't have a trailing slash in `location  /movies/` - I have just `location /movies`.

Comment: @muru thanks. I have tried different combinations of slashes but they all seem to 301 redirect back to `/`

Comment: @the_velour_fog I cannot reproduce the problem on `nginx` 1.8.0

Comment: @RichardSmith that could be possible. Im running `nginx version: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)` I don't know if I'm being affected by it, but there is mention [on this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21401899/4668401) of a bug around the `alias` directive

Comment: I'm also running 1.4.6 (`1.4.6-1ubuntu3.3`).